# Laravel 5.3 Ajax url not found

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm working on a screen with the following url `http://localhost/npr/public/admin/athletes/test/143` 
On this screen, I've implemented the following dynamic droplist Ajax call that's not found:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('select[name="section"]').on('change', function() {

     var sectionID = $(this).val();

     if(sectionID) {
         $.ajax({
             url: './getSportPositions'+sectionID,
             method: 'get',
             //data: {"_token": $('#token').val()},
             dataType: "json",
             success:function(data) {
                 $('select[name="position"]').empty();
                 $('select[name="position"]').append('<option value="">'+ '-- Please choose one --' +'</option>');
                 $.each(data, function(i, position) {
                     $('select[name="position"]').append('<option value="'+position.name+'">'+ position.name +'</option>');
                 });
             }
         });
     }else{
         $('select[name="position"]').empty();
     }
 });
});
```

Route:

`Route::get('getSportPositions{id}','HomeController@getSportPositions');`

I've also tried with:

`Route::get('/admin/athletes/test/getSportPositions{id}','HomeController@getSportPositions');`

Is it due to athlete ID 143 in the calling URL? How do I fix this call?
It seems from the error that it's trying to access this route:

```
Route::get('/admin/athletes/test/{athlete}/', [
    'uses' => 'HomeController@testAnAthlete',
    'as' => 'admin.test_athlete'
]);
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('position') ? ' alert alert-danger' : '' }}">
        <label for="position" class="col-md-3 control-label">Position in Team</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="form-control" name="position" id="position">
                @if (!$errors->has('position'))
                  <option selected value> -- select a team first --  </option>
                @endif
            </select>
        </div>
        @if ($errors->has('position'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('position') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif                                        
    </div>
```

Comment: please add select html code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using Ajax you have to get url  like

```
var APP_URL = $('meta[name="_base_url"]').attr('content');
```

also add this 
`<meta name="_base_url" content="{{ url('/') }}">`
to head tag

then after you can use APP_URL

```
var url = APP_URL+"/getSportPositions/"+sectionID;
```

Comment: I don't have a problem getting the url with ./ notation. I added your code now and the problem with the 143 id is still there. It's now routing to `http://localhost/npr/public/admin/athletes/test/undefined/getSportPositions/4`

Comment: Can you paste APP_URL here?

Comment: Route should be    

`Route::get('getSportPositions/{id}','HomeController@getSportPositions');`

instead of 
   `Route::get('getSportPositions{id}','HomeController@getSportPositions');`

Comment: APP_URL is undefined.

Comment: Did you try this?
`var APP_URL = $('meta[name="_base_url"]').attr('content');`

Comment: Jip. It's undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144522/discussion-between-nikhil-radadiya-and-louisav).

Answer (score 0):

Additional from me. in laravel view :

```
<meta name="_base_url" content="{{ url('/') }}">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

in addition to **@Nikhil Radadiya** answer, because using jquery mean you wait for page ready, you can use javascript :

```
var APP_URL = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')._base_url.content;
var APP_CSRF = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").content; // javascript cannot use dash, else you can use csrf_token at meta name
```

then you can use in your ajax like :

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': APP_CSRF
    },
    url: APP_URL + '/your_ajax_path',
    ...
    ...
});
```

and make sure the url is loaded in your web route.

Answer (score 0):

You could name the route and use BLADE to set a Javascript variable to that route.

For example:

```
Route::get('/', 'MyAmazingController@function')->name('my.awesome.route');
```

Then in your Javascript you can do something like:

```
url: '{{ route('my.awesome.route') }}';
```

If you have the javascript in a seperate file, you could create a constant in your view with routes in it.

```
val ROUTES = {
    AJAX: '{{ route('my.awesome.route') }}'
}
```