# How to avoid or prevent 500 Internal Server Error after executing AJAX script?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have modified an AJAX script for Modal CRUD in my project because I have trouble in decoding some provided samples. However I encountered this problem in my AJAX Delete script with the console says:

> POST http://localhost:8000/deleteItem 500 (Internal Server Error)
>   send  @   app.js:10552 ajax   @   app.js:10159
>   (anonymous)   @   dept_pagination:944 dispatch    @   app.js:6192
>   elemData.handle   @   app.js:6000

I noticed 'deleteItem' is not the url I am redirecting to. In my Ajax script I indicated 'deleteItem_dept' but after executing, it works well but the console throws this error and the url is changed to 'deleteItem' which is the url for the other page view. Below is my Ajax Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function dept_delete(id)
    {
      $('#footer_action_button_dept').text(" Yes");
      $('#footer_action_button_dept').removeClass('glyphicon-check');
      $('#footer_action_button_dept').addClass('glyphicon-trash');
      $('.actionBtndept').removeClass('btn-success');
      $('.actionBtndept').addClass('btn-info');
      $('.actionBtndept').addClass('delete');
      $('.id').text($(this).data('id'));
      $('#deleteContentdept').show();
      $('.form-horizontal').show();
      $('#delModal').modal('show');

    $('.modal-footer').on('click','#deldept', function(){
          if (id == '')
          {
            alert('No department selected.')
          }
          else
          {
            $.ajax({
              url: "/deleteItem_dept",
              type: "post",
              data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'id': id
              },
                success: function(data) {
                  document.getElementById(id).remove();
                  id = undefined; //reset ID to undefined
                  $('.form-horizontal').show();
                }
            });
          }
      });
      $('.modal-footer').on('click','#candept', function(){
        id = undefined; //reset ID to undefined
        $('.form-horizontal').show();
      });
    }
</script>
```

Controller logic

```
public function deleteItem_dept(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->id;
    DeptOffice::where('id', $data)->delete();
    return response()->json();
}
```

Comment: Can you share the delete route and controller? Typically you pass the item id to delete in the url.

Comment: public function deleteItem_dept(Request $request) {
        $data = $request->id;
        DeptOffice::where('id',$data)->delete();
        return response()->json();
    }

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027877/laravel-5-3-ajax-url-not-found/44040433#44040433

Comment: can you apply to my code?

Comment: @ResnefImmatong Please follow instructions from that post and you will get it working

Comment: script is working fine and my controller is responding well... but why does the console throw this 500 Internal server error?

Comment: Your Ajax request is fine. Issue is in the controller section only.

Comment: @Akilan can you point which line in my controller, please.

Answer (score 0):

It should be handle in your controller. Check first if the object exist

```
public function deleteItem_dept(Request $request) { 
    $data = $request->id; 
    if ($record = DeptOffice::where('id',$data)->first()) {
        $record->delete()
    } 
    return response()->json(); 
}
```

Comment: @ResnefImmatong updated the answer to check the data first

Comment: still the same, it also throws the alert message but console still with error result.